# One to many relation: retrieving documents with a single query

Tags: mongodb, one-to-many

Returning to classic mongodb example (posts and users):

Posts:

```
{title: "Greetings", body:"Hello world", userId:12345}
```

Users:

```
{_id:12345, name:"John Smith", email:john@smith.org"}
```

How to get post

```
{title: "Greetings", body:"Hello world", <username>:"John Smith"}
```

with a sigle query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Combine data from multiple collections into one..how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB is not an RDBMS - so NO JOINS - either you use two queries or you use embedding or you look at "database references".

Comment: Can you add a source to your answer?