# How can I effectively join 2 huge collections in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I have two huge (few hundred thousands of records) collections `Col1` and `Col2`, and I need to fetch joined data from both of them. There is a join criteria that lets me dramatically decrease number of records returned to few hundreds, so in SQL language I would run something like

```
 SELECT ... FROM Col1 INNER JOIN Col2 ON Col1.field1 = Col2.field2
```

and it would run pretty fast as `Col1.field1` and `Col2.field2` are indexed fields. Is there any direct way or workaround to do the same thing fast in MongoDb with indexes usage, not to scan all the items?

Note: I cannot redesign collections to merge them into one.

Comment: we have a similar situation. Did you find a way to improve join performance between 2 x collections that have an indexed foreign key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB has no JOIN so there is not a fast equivalent. It is most likely a schema design issue but you said you can't change that.  You can't query multiple collections in one query.

You can either do the join client-side in 2 queries or you can do it in non-live style by doing a map-reduce and generating a 3rd collection.

Reference [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-in-to-one-how) for details on how to do a map-reduce

Comment: Both ways you mentioned suppose iteration through all half a million records of at least one of collection which is performance killer, and I need to do it in run-time, not somewhere in background. I do not think it's a schema design issue, it's rather issue of selected database type, MongoDb seems do not fit well our application requirements

Comment: Thats is what I meant. Its a schema design issue for the database selected. Ideally you would have stored this under a single collection.  Its not an efficient situation for this DB

Comment: The thing is that storing this information into one collection might increase database size hundreds times as there are hundreds ways to join this 2 collections, keeping them separate means data denormalization, merging them together means excessive size of database and many repeated data. Even if I can redesign schema I would not do it. So my conclusion is that MongoDb is just not flexible enough as relational databases are. Thanks anyway for the response

Comment: @YMC why on earth would you need to run a real time select of half a million rows? What user would be able to display all of that data? I think you need to rethink what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

In order to join in MongoDb 4.2 you can use aggregation and $lookup like this query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $lookup: { from: "...", ... } }
])
```

It is usefull for me

More information: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: This was available in Mongo3.2, not 4. Also, this doesn't have great performance

Comment: The performance is a problem: https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/comparison-joins-mongodb-vs-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

the `join` in MongoDB is so expensive. 2 solutions:

- Redesign merge them into one
- `limit`, `match` before you join