# Import of one to many relationships to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a large amount of data in a relational database that I want to import into Mongodb. The data exists in two tables that have a one to many relationship and I would therefore like to arrange for the final mongo collection to have rows from the second table stored as sub-documents inside docs containing data from the first table.

Using mongoimport I can only bring in flat structures if I use csv format (easy to export from original db) otherwise I have to export from the original db in json format with the full nested structure (very hard)

I have tried importing each table to a different collection and then using the map-reduce technique cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-in-to-one-how) but this results in the fields of the top level document being wrapped inside another object which is not very satisfactory.

I feel this must be a very common use case, but can't find any guide as to how to solve it. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, map-reduce in mongo assumes a key with a single value document - which is why you end up with the documents with just two objects, a key and a (complex, nested) value object.

You could write some code to translate your .csv files into .json.

Alternatively, here is a bit of a hack. I exported the data (after using the map-reduce process) to json using **mongoexport**, used **sed** to unpack the value object, and then imported it back in using **mongoimport**.  If you use pipes, you don't need to save the whole file at any time (sed is a streaming editor).  For the example in the other post you referenced, you use this:

```
mongoexport -c users_comments | sed 's/\"value\" : {//' | sed s/\}$// | mongoimport -c user_comments2
```

This one-liner will duplicate the user_comments collection and store it in a new collection, user_comments2. If you have more disk space, you could save the export file and drop the user_comments collection after you export it, then import the file.  It takes a couple of lines:

```
mongoexport -c users_comments | sed 's/\"value\" : {//' | sed s/\}$// > export.json
# now use mongo to drop the user_comments collection, and then:
mongoimport -c user_comments < export.json
```

Assumptions are that the _id doesn't include the string "value", and that you've already used mongoimport to import that data, so suffered any data loss that it entails.  I've tested this on small data sets.  I would not recommend this approach on a live production database.