# mongodb insert embedded documents from other collections massive collections using map reduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, bigdata, database

these files that i will be getting have at least a million rows each, max 1.5 billion. The data is **normalized** when i get it. I need a way to store it in **one** document. For the most part i am not 100% how the data will be given to me. it could be csv, Fixed Width Text File or tsv or something else.

currently i have some collections that i imported from some sample csv's.

bellow is a small representation of my data missing fields

in my beneficaries.csv the data is **repeated**

beneficaries.csv over 6 million records

```
record # 1
{"userid":"a9dk4kJkj",
 "gender":"male",
 "dob":20080514,
 "start_date":20000101,
 "end_date":20080227}

record # 2
{"userid":"a9dk4kJkj",
 "gender":"male",
 "dob":20080514,
 "start_date":20080201,
 "end_date":00000000}

 same user different start and end dates
```

claims.csv over 200 million records

```
{"userid":"a9dk4kJkj",
     "date":20080514,
     "code":"d4rd3",
     "blah":"data"}
```

lab.csv over 10 million records

```
{"userid":"a9dk4kJkj",
     "date":20080514,
     "lab":"mri",
     "blah":"data"}
```

From my limited knowledge i have three option

1. sort the files, read x amount in our c++ Member objects from the data files, stop at y, insert the members into mongodb, move on to starting at y for x members until we are done. This is **Tested** and **Working** but sorting such massive files will kill our machine for hours.

   2. load data to sql, read one by one into c++ Member objects, bulk load the data in mongo. Tested and works but, but i would like to avoid this very much.
   3. load the documents in mongo in seperate collections and perform a map-reduction with out parameter to wrtie to collection. I have the documents loaded (as shown above) in there own collections for each file. Unfortunately i am new to mongo and on a deadline. The map-reduction concept is difficult for me to wrap my head around and implement. I have read the docs and tried using this answer on stack overflow [MongoDB: Combine data from multiple collections into one..how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how)

The output **member** collection should look like this.

```
{"userid":"aaa4444",
 "gender":"female",
 "dob":19901225,
 "beneficiaries":[{"start_date":20000101,
                  "end_date":20080227},
                  {"start_date":20008101,
                  "end_date":00000000}],
"claims":[{"date":20080514,
         "code":"d4rd3",
         "blah":"data"},
        {"date":20080514,
         "code":"d4rd3",
         "blah":"data"}],
"labs":[{"date":20080514,
         "lab":"mri",
         "blah":"data"}]}
```

Would the performance of load data to sql, read in c++ and insert into mongodb beat the map reduction? if so i will stick with that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, your data are good candidates for map-reduce, hence would be better to go for option 3: load the documents in mongo in 3 seperate collections: `beneficiaries`, `claims`, `labs` and perform map-reduce on the `userid` key on each collections. Finally, integrate the data from 3 collections into single collections using find and insert on the `userid` key.

Assume you load `beneficiaries.csv` into collection `beneficiaries`, this is the sample code for map-reduce on beneficiaries:

```
mapBeneficiaries = function() {
    var values = {
        start_date: this.start_date,
        end_date: this.end_date,
        userid: this.userid,
        gender: this.gender,
        dob: this.dob
    };
    emit(this.userid, values);
};

reduce = function(k, values) {
  list = { beneficiaries: [], gender : '', dob: ''};
  for(var i in values) {
    list.beneficiaries.push({start_date: values[i].start_date, end_date: values[i].end_date});
    list.gender = values[i].gender;
    list.dob = values[i].dob;
  }
  return list;
};

db.beneficiaries.mapReduce(mapBeneficiaries, reduce, {"out": {"reduce": "mr_beneficiaries"}});
```

The output in `mr_beneficiaries` will be like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "a9dk4kJkj",
    "value" : {
        "beneficiaries" : [ 
            {
                "start_date" : 20080201,
                "end_date" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "start_date" : 20080201,
                "end_date" : 0
            }
        ],
        "gender" : "male",
        "dob" : 20080514
    }
}
```

Do the same thing to obtain `mp_claims` and `mp_labs`. Then integrate into `singledocuments`:

```
db.mr_beneficiaries.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var id = doc._id;
    var claims = db.mr_claims.findOne({"_id":id});
    var labs = db.mr_lab.findOne({"_id":id});
    db.singledocuments.insert({"userid":id,
                         "gender":doc.value.gender,
                         "dob":doc.value.dob,
                         "beneficiaries":doc.value.beneficiaries,
                         "claims":claims.value.claims,
                         "labs":labs.value.labs});
});
```

Comment: i cant use map reduction for inserting claims and lab? wouldnt that run faster

Comment: also i would findOne wont do it there are multiple claims and multiple lab

Comment: After mapreduce you will have one claims/lab list per userid so findOne is fine

Comment: You can use mapreduce to insert claims and lab into the same document in mr_beneficiaries by setting the same "out" . But the output format won't be what you want

Comment: I think the best solution for me would be to put every csv in one collection, then Use map reduce by id and form the new collection. Since the user id is used all acoss this should work fine. Thank you for the working beneficary example and demonstratimg how i could use map reduce on this data. I had a hard time grasping the concept from the docs until i ran your working example on the data i was familar with