# mongodb join in meteor

Tags: mongodb, join, meteor, database

I have two collection

Products

```
    "_id" : "1",
    "Product" : "Phone",
    "Godown" :"Godown1",
    "Info" : [
            {
                    "Type":"iphone",
                    "Quantity" : "10",
                    "Price" : "30000"
            },
            {
                    "Type":"Samsung",
                    "Quantity" : "10",
                    "Price" : "30000"
            }
            ]})
```

and Sales

```
"_id" : "5551",
"Product" : "Phone",
"Godown" :"Godown1",        
"Type":"iphone",
"Quantity" : "10",
"Price" : "30000"
```

If i want merge this collection into one and store it in a variable is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, this is not necessary, but a problem in data modeling. Ask yourself what you really want to achieve. Usually, querying related data boils down to

> For a ***given*** `X`, what is the related `Y`?

As per your example:

> For `"Info.Type" == iphone`, what is the related sales document?

Which in shell terms would be easy to look up with

```
db.sales.find({"Type":"iphone"})
```

Now that you have the `Products` document *and* the related `Sales` document available, you can merge them within your code for delivery to the client, for example. One of my MongoDB mantras

> Keep the logic where it belongs to – your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MapReduce: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/#MapReduce-Outputoptions

For details see this answer: [MongoDB: Combine data from multiple collections into one..how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how)

To access raw collection/db use rawCollection() on Mongo.Collection - http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-104-mongo-cordova-template-subscriptions