# How to combine data documents from three collections into one single collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following three collections in MongoDB

```
fd2k10sample
fd2k16sample
fd2ksample
```

the documents in each of them are of same structure so no structure problem as below:

**fd2ksample**

```
id  cat1    cat2     cat3   cat4
1   doza    moza     goza   hoza
2   beta    geta     jeta   leta
3   huggy   muggy    guggy  luggy
```

**fd2k10sample**

```
id cat1     cat2    cat3    cat4
1  prizzy   mizzy   tizzy   hizzy
2  chuta    buta    guta    tuta
3  befer    lefer   gefer   tefer
```

**fd2k16sample**

```
id  cat1   cat2   cat3   cat4
1   poopa  doopa  hoopa  loopa
2   nijjy  pijjy  hijjy  tijjy
3   ufha   puhfa  duhfa  tuhfa
```

How do I combine them like so:

**fd2kfullsample**

```
id   cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4
1   doza    moza     goza   hoza
2   beta    geta     jeta   leta
3   huggy   muggy    guggy  luggy
1   poopa  doopa     hoopa  loopa
2   nijjy  pijjy     hijjy  tijjy
3   ufha   puhfa     duhfa  tuhfa
1   poopa  doopa     hoopa  loopa
2   nijjy  pijjy     hijjy  tijjy
3   ufha   puhfa     duhfa  tuhfa
```

How to do this with just few commands in MongoDB version 3.4?

The answer given in this solution is about Merging the Data Documents whereas I want to combine the data documents not merge them.
The below is not a duplicate but a different question altogether:
[MongoDB: Combine data from multiple collections into one..how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how)

Comment: Do not agree with the answers @chridam The Answers given there do not address combining they are about merging collections I want to combining as given in the example above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily achive this with [copyTo()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/)

to merge your 3 collections into one, just run the following commands:

```
db.fd2k10sample.copyTo("fd2kfullsample")
db.fd2k16sample.copyTo("fd2kfullsample")
db.fd2ksample.copyTo("fd2kfullsample")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this bang on target. I am using it now and it works. Thanks you saved me a lot of time @felix

Comment: Your Question is unique and I faced a similar issue this solution by @felix worked for me Thx for your answer