# Export multiple collection with pointer to single JSON file

Tags: mongodb, export, parse-server

I would like to export multiple mongo collection to single JSON file.

For easy understanding, lets define the sample collections below

Collection 1: **Order**

```
{
    "_id": "01LS0PnHCR",
    "title": "Test Title",
    "when": {
        "$date": "2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "_p_orderData": "OrderData$02OOnDuJnM", // Reference of OrderData collection -> 02OOnDuJnM
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-27T12:24:30.449Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-02-01T12:48:46.026Z"
    },
    "_p_user": "_User$hCiOOgQkOC"       // Reference of _User collection -> hCiOOgQkOC
}
```

Collection 2: **OrderData**

```
{
    "_id": "02OOnDuJnM",
    "orderDescription": "Test Description",
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-11T21:23:01.132Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-11T21:23:01.132Z"
    }
}
```

Collection 3: **OrderComment**

```
{
    "_id": "04tNm4U7sm",
    "_p_order": "Order$01LS0PnHCR",     // Reference of Order collection -> 01LS0PnHCR
    "type": "text",
    "comment": "cute",
    "_p_user": "_User$BKOIWDtzQ0",      // Reference of _User collection -> BKOIWDtzQ0
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-06T13:47:14.478Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-06T13:47:14.478Z"
    }
}
```

Collection 4: **_User**

```
{
    "_id": "hCiOOgQkOC",
    "username": "testing",
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-11T07:52:14.157Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-02-09T22:13:16.904Z"
    },
    "firstName": "Tes",
    "email": "testing@gmail.com",
    "lastName": "Ing"
}
```

My question as follows

1. How to export the above 4 collections to single json as follows

   `{
       "_id": "01LS0PnHCR",
       "title": "Test Title",
       "when": {
           "$date": "2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"
       },
       "_p_orderData": {
           "_id": "02OOnDuJnM",
           "orderDescription": "Test Description",
           "_created_at": {
               "$date": "2017-01-11T21:23:01.132Z"
           },
           "_updated_at": {
               "$date": "2017-01-11T21:23:01.132Z"
           }
           },

       "_created_at": {
           "$date": "2017-01-27T12:24:30.449Z"
       },
       "_updated_at": {
           "$date": "2017-02-01T12:48:46.026Z"
       },
       "_p_user": {
           "_id": "hCiOOgQkOC",
           "username": "testing",
           "_created_at": {
               "$date": "2017-01-11T07:52:14.157Z"
           },
           "_updated_at": {
               "$date": "2017-02-09T22:13:16.904Z"
           },
           "firstName": "Tes",
           "email": "testing@gmail.com",
           "lastName": "Ing"
           },

       "OrderComment": [ // New attribute added to dream with array of comments

           {
           "_id": "04tNm4U7sm",
           "_p_order": "Order$01LS0PnHCR",

           "type": "text",
           "comment": "cute",
           "_p_user": "_User$BKOIWDtzQ0",

           "_created_at": {
               "$date": "2017-01-06T13:47:14.478Z"
           },
           "_updated_at": {
               "$date": "2017-01-06T13:47:14.478Z"
           }
           }
       ]
   }`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how

Comment: Error: field names cannot start with $ [$date]

Comment: @KevinSmith: It get from MLAB mongo data and modified the values. It refer the date object I think.