# Merge collections in Mongodb 3.4.4

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Imagine that I've the following document in collection A:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "ratio" : 6.0
}
```

I've also the following documents in collection B:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : 1,
    ratio : 3.0
  },
  {
    "_id" : 2,
    ratio : 4.0
  }
]
```

How can I **merge** them together to produce the following output:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : 1,
    ratio : 6.0
  },
  {
    "_id" : 2,
    ratio : 4.0
  }
]
```

So, as you can see above:

- When `collectionA._id` matches to `collectionB._id`, it produces the ratio from `collectionA` as the result,
- When ids don't match, it takes the ratio from `collectionB`.
- `collectionA` will not have ids which doesn't exist in `collectionB`, because, I derive `collectionB` from `collectionA` in a prior aggregation.
- And, for example, if there are more ids in `collectionB`, they will be added to the output as well.

**So, basically, `collectionA` overwrites `collectionB` and then the unmatched docs from `collectionB` is added to the result, as well.**

---

This is trivial to implement in my app code however there are millions of records exist in my database so I want to do it in MongoDB. I know also that [there is no full-outer-join in MongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23201), is there a way to achieve the result?

Comment: what if there is _id = 3 in collection B?

Comment: it'll be added to the output as well.

Comment: This is trivial to implement by just reading both collections and merging them in the app.

Comment: Yeah, I know but there are millions of records, so I want to do it through MongoDB.

Comment: "when collectionA._id matches to collectionB._id, it produces the collectionB.ratio" - your output contradicts this assertion. And the next one.

Comment: afaik you can do only inner join or left join in mongo

Comment: "when collectionA._id matches to collectionB._id, it produces the collectionA.ratio, but, when it doesn't match, it produces collectionA.ratio." - soo, it's collectionA always?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, but, I also want to add the collectionB's docs if collectionA doesn't contain them.

Comment: @inanc: I suggest you rephrase that. Sounds weird.

Comment: If there are millions, maybe you could do this incrementally in bunches

Comment: Yeah, but that won't be trivial, and I'll be doing it that way if there's no other solution. Keeping this in database is more logical because I declare that I want this and database will also optimize it in the future versions. However, my app will not.

Answer (score -1):

> So, basically, collectionA overwrites collectionB and then the
>   unmatched docs from collectionB are added to the result, as well.

You can do only left joins with MongoDB, so you cannot select documents from collectionB which not match any document in collectionA when you query collectionA. Thus you should do it in two queries. First one simply selects documents from collectionA (these documents overwrite documents from collectionB anyway, so we are not interested in documents from collectionB wich match documents in collectionA).

And second query - get documents from collectionB which don't match any documents in collectionA:

```
db.collectionB.aggregate([
 {
    $lookup: {
       from: "collectionA",
       localField: "_id",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "docs"
    }       
 },
 { $match: { docs: {$eq: [] } } },
 { $project: { docs: 0 } }
])
```

Comment: Thx, so how to combine the both queries' result into a collection again? Like as the output that I needed in the question? [MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how#8746805)?

Comment: @inanc it depends on the way you want to use the data. What do you want to do with results?

Comment: I'll display the merged results on a webpage.