# Improve performance of find_by method matching strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, erb, findby

Pardon my Ruby/Rails ignorance, I'm still learning.

**Details:**
I have two mongodb tables. `people` has 214 records, `people_org` has 107, this will only increase in the future. The only unique connection between these tables is a person's name, which is on average ~15 characters. I do not have control over this DB structure at this time.

Currently I'm looping through each `people` object, then using `find_by` to find the matching record, printing an ID that I need, and printing some information.

```
<%@people.each do |p|%>
...
    <%=@people_org.find_by(name: p.name).id%>
    ...[priting a few paragraphs of text]...
    <%end%>
...
<%end%>
```

**Problem:**
The performance is quite slow (~10 seconds).

**Potential Solutions:**
(1) Our team may adapt to a structure that does not rely on string matching and use integers instead (I assume this would improve performance).

(2) Perhaps there is a more efficient method?

(3) Perhaps there is a way to prepare or alter the data for a more effcient sort?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have any assocition between `people` and `people_org` ?

Comment: You can use the lookup aggregation provided by MongoDB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948843/2100645

Comment: are you using mongoid?

Comment: quite slow? 10s is abysmal, especially for a few hundred records.

Comment: (3) : You can grab all the `PeopleOrg` records before displaying the page and try to look for them in the view: `@people_orgs_grouped_by_name = PeopleOrg.where(name: @people.pluck(:name)).group_by(&:name)` and then in the view use `if @people_orgs_grouped_by_name[p.name].present?` etc. (1) yes, you should define a relation between the 2 models without using the name, because Bob (id 1) is not the same as Bob (id 2) but will still be grabbed by this code

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I'll be back soon

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you can utilise [MongoDB Aggregation operator $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to perform lookup operation to another collection.

For example, having MongoDB documents in `people` collection such below:

```
{ "name": "Brandon", 
  "phone": 123456789 }
```

also an example of documents in `people_org` collection as below:

```
{ "organisation": "NBCC", 
  "contact": "Brandon"}
```

You can use [MongoDB Ruby Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-aggregation/) example as below to lookup `people` by name to `people_org`:

```
cursor = collection.aggregate([
                   {"$match":
                          {"name":"Brandon"}}, 
                   {"$lookup": 
                          {"from": "people_org", 
                           "localField": "name", 
                           "foreignField": "contact", 
                           "as": "organisation"}
                   }])
cursor.each do |document|
    puts document
end
```

Note that `$lookup` is available only since MongoDB v3.2+