# Query Mongo collection by array property intersect with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have simple query that results with array:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection')
    .find( {
               _id: '5c1286ed222a6e0e4acbd018'
           }, 
           {
               myProperty: 1, 
               _id: 0 
           })
```

Result:

```
{
    "myProperty" : [ 
        "5c1286ed222a6e0e4acbd017"
    ]
}
```

I want to query another collection with this result.
The other collection (let call it yourCollection) has property 'yourProperty' which is the same kind of array like the result.

```
db.getCollection('scene').find({
// all the objects where 'yourProperty' contains at least one element of
// the first query result.
'yourProperty': containsAny() //Something like that
})
```

My goal is to get all elements of 'yourCollection' where its property 'yourProperty' has at least one element that is resulted with first query above.

Comment: Try using the $lookup from MongoDB aggregation framework. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Combine data from multiple collections into one..how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how)