# How to combine two the same collections in one collection in mongo db? (like union all in MySql)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

for example I have collection_1 with this data:
"_id": "60d75ed08af96529bf605030"
"Fname": "some name"
"Lname": "some last name"
"Age": "20"
"sex": "Woman"
"Previous_job": "Arsen"

and collection two with this data:
"_id": "60d75ed08af96529bf605030"
"Fname": "some name"
"Lname": "some last name"
"Age": "20"
"sex": "Woman"
"Previous_job": "Arsen"

I know how I can make it in MySQL using UNION ALL but I don't know how to make it in mongo db,
how can I combine these collections in one collection?
can give answer in Russian or Ukraine

Comment: the first google link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Combine data from multiple collections into one..how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how)

Comment: can you write slip code for example please? I spent a lot time for search in google and I been in the first link but I didn't find any answer