Mongodb two collection connection with foreign key
I am using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in the frontend, and Node.js in the backend. For the database, I am using MongoDB. Before adding the authentication page, when random users attempted the quiz, their marks were saved in the MongoDB 'quizresults' collection. However, after adding the authentication page, when users successfully registered, their data started saving in the MongoDB 'user' collection. But after login, when users submit the quiz, their marks are displayed on the screen, yet the data is not saving in the 'quizresults' collection in MongoDB. To resolve this problem, I have attempted to establish a connection between the two collections, 'users' and 'quizresults', but the problem still persists.
user.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;

quizResult.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const quizResultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User', // Refers to the 'User' model
        required: true
    },
    correctAnswers: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    totalQuestions: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    totalScore: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

const QuizResult = mongoose.model('QuizResult', quizResultSchema);

module.exports = QuizResult;

authRoutes.js
// authRoutes.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');

// Route for user registration (POST request)
router.post('/register', authController.register);

// Route for user login (POST request)
router.post('/login', authController.login);

module.exports = router;

userRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { authenticateUser } = require('../middlewares/authMiddleware');
const { generateToken } = require('../utils/jwtUtils');

// Placeholder route handler for user login
router.post('/login', authenticateUser, (req, res) => {
    // Handle user login logic here
    // Assuming the user is authenticated, generate a JWT token
    const token = generateToken(req.user.userId);
    // Send the token back to the client
    res.json({ token });
});

module.exports = router;

app.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const User = require('./models/user');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');

const app = express();

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/stallman', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

// Generate a secure random string to use as a session secret
const sessionSecret = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({
  secret: sessionSecret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Passport Configuration
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, async (email, password, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found.' });
    }
    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!match) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
    }
    return done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);
  }
});

// Serve static files from the public directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Routes
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);

// Define route for the login page
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'login.html'));
});

// Define route for the register page
app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'register.html'));
});

// Define route for user login
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      console.log('User not found:', email);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User not found.' });
    }
    console.log('Stored Password:', user.password);
    console.log('Provided Password:', password);
    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    console.log('Password Match:', match);
    if (!match) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Incorrect password.' });
    }
    // Redirect to homepage after successful login
    res.redirect('/');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during login:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Define route for the root path
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

i already tries these link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how
https://hevodata.com/learn/mongodb-join-two-collections/

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/core/views/join-collections-with-view/

i want to join two collection via foreign key, when users login their quiz result will be submit in 'quizresult' collection

Did you call .save() on the collection or instance?  I don't see in your code where you save the QuizResults.
Something like:
const doc = new QuizResult();
doc.user = '6592008029c8c3e4dc76256c';
doc.correctAnswers = 5;
doc.totalQuestions = 5;
doc.totalScore = 100;
await doc.save();

I don't see anywhere in your code that you save the document to the QuizResult collections.
Note: Mongodb is Non relational so there are no concepts of foreign keys but you can embed and find doc references with $lookup. In mongoose they make this  easy using .populate() method on an document instance.
